# Azure DevOps triggering build only on project, affected by last commit in PR

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have several projects in one repository in Azure DevOps.

Let's name projects: A and B.

We configured 2 pipelines.

We configured Build Validation rules for pull requests, for A:

[image]

and similar for B.

**Scenario**

- Create branch
- Update files in directories of 2 projects: A and B. Commit & push.
- Create PR → pipelines for projects A and B are triggered and finished. It's ok.
- Update files in directory of project A, commit & push → pipelines for A and B are triggered again.

**Expected behavior**: only A should be triggered, because all changes to B already verified by previous build and in last commit it’s not changed.

On the screenshot we can see phrase: Automatic **(whenever the source branch is updated)**. Does it means that pipeline will be triggered if branch contains changes on matched path, regardless if this path was updated by last commit? It's not very convenient, because we don't want to rebuild project once again if previous build was finished and then nothing is changed.

Comment: Just to be clear, the build policy configuration is only for the builds triggered on the PR.  It doesn't have any impact on the CI configuration of a commit on the target branch.  You mean specifically that both build policy builds are running?  Or after the PR is completed, you are seeing both A and B build?

Comment: I mean both pipelines are executed: at first when PR is created (which is ok), and second time, when we do second push to branch (where I expect that only affected project will be built). This is before completion of PR.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are talking about two projects or two branches?

Comment: Two projects inside one repository, each is built independently of another.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you'll be able to achieve your goal using two projects in the same repository, however, have you considered using triggers? meaning only when project A or B is changed your pipeline will be triggered. But I think you'll have to clone your pipeline anyway, check this out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml